# What is this scale? [Root , +1 , +3 , +1 , +2 , +1 , +3 , +1]

Tags: scales, intervals

Intervals (relative to previous note):

Root , +1 , +3 , +1 , +2 , +1 , +3 , +1 (Root again)

Example:

A, Bb, C#, D, E, F, G#

This scale is used often in Turkish Music. But I don't know if it has a name in Western Music.  Does it ?

Comment: This scale is known as the Phrygian Dominant scale.

Comment: I've only seen Phrygian Dominant used to describe a mode of the harmonic minor scale starting on the 5th scale degree, which would only have a single augmented second in it, not two as in the question.

Comment: @PatMuchmore exactly. However, this scale feels very similar to the harmonic minor scale. I think this is because of the major 7th. And I think this scale is occasionally used in western music too, by mixing with other minor scales, just like harmonic minor.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw, Agreed. I would say that it's the augmented seconds that make the strongest connection to harmonic minor though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The technical term for the scale seems to be the  Minor "Gypsy" Scale and it is also known as the Flamenco Mode.

The basic idea is it is a combination of two Phrygian Dominant tetrachords, or a Phrygian Dominant with a Major 7th scale degree.

Here are the links that show both scales match the pattern above and includes the root scale of it the Phrygian Dominant scale:

[Minor Gypsy Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsy_scale#Minor_Gypsy_scale)

[Flamenco Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco_mode)

[Phrygian Dominant Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_dominant_scale)

Answer (score 9):

*Maqam Suzidil* (not a very Western name, but if you try to understand Turkish music, this might get you somewhere) says [this](http://www.oud.eclipse.co.uk/suzidilarab.html) and some other sites. Looks like they (Arabic, Persian, Turkish) have an interesting way of classifying the scales by decomposing them into (usually) tetrachords which all have their own "personality". I didn't explore this much but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_maqam#Ajnas) gives some introduction.

Answer (score 6):

That scale is known as the Double Harmonic scale (at least that's the title of its Wikipedia page [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale)).

Comment: This is also the name by which I know this scale, although it seems there are many alternative (equally valid) names.

Comment: +1 this is the name I've heard it called by most often. This video by 12-Tone does a great job explaining it: https://youtu.be/n7hSabSnCEg

Answer (score 4):

As an answer to this question : [What is this scale? Possibly an Indian Raga](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/60652/what-is-this-scale-possibly-an-indian-raga)

In Indian classical music, this scale is of [Raag Bhairav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhairav_(raga)) in Hindustani classical music (central and northern India).
It corresponds to [Mayamalavagowla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayamalavagowla) in Carnatic (south Indian) music.

Answer (score 1):

Double Harmonic. Hijaz Kar (Arabic). Suzidil (Turkish). Chromatic, as per Byzantine Liturgical practice. As someone else noted earlier, Rhaag Bhairav. That intervallic pattern, even if the exact intonation is different from tradition to tradition, is quite common.

Answer (score -3):

Closest I found was a Spanish Phrygian 
1 - ♭2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - ♭6 - ♭7 - 1

only difference is the 7th degree...maybe your scale has accidental on the 7th