# Double-klezmer notes

Tags: theory, scales, terminology, klezmer

I am curious about the klezmer scale. I mean exactly the half, 1.5, and the half note series gives the mood. What about doubling this 4 note series in an octave? Does it have a name? I mean for example:

```
E , F, G#, A, B, C, D#, E
```

I know an oriental piece in my mind written on these order.

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/13955/45266

Answer (score 4):

It does have a name and it is know as the E [double harmonic major scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale). The reason it sounds exotic and foreign is due to the Augmented step between the 2nd and 3rd and 6th and 7th.

The scale pattern in general is:

```
H - A - H - W - H - A - H
```

Which applied to C would be

```
C - D♭ - E - F - G - A♭ - B
```